# C# how to do nopcommerce custom shipping calculations ?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I'm using nopcommerce open source  for a customer .I want to do a custom shipping calculations.
Here are rules for my shipping calculation.

```
Ex: 1-5 items :$ 5 
    6-10 items: $10
Additional item :$2
```

How do i do this in nopcommerce?
Should i write a new shipping module or is there already smiler shipping module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new shipping computation plugin.

The easiest way is to copy from another plugin such as Shipping.FixedRateShipping and change the name.

Then modify the method GetFixedRate to return the rate depending on the number of quantities, etc..

Follow these steps to install and configure your plugin: http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/77/how-to-write-a-nopcommerce-plugin.aspx

I hope this helps.